# Es bueno recargar una web cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: php, html, web

lo que sucede es que tengo una pagina html la cual se recarga cada minuto para actualizar una tabla, mi pregunta es si es bueno hacer esa practica ya que requiero estar actualizando esa pagina no se si eso genera trafico o gasta mucho ancho de banda en fin no se mucho del tema de servidores pero cualquier aporte me es útil gracias.

este es el código html que utilizo

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
```

Comment: No, no es una buena práctica, deberías actualizar solamente el contenido de la tabla a través de AJAX

Comment: @MarceloForclaz AJAX era la solución adecuada en 2010, ahora hay muchas otras.

Comment: @Shaz me refería a AJAX como punto de partida. Es mejor que actualizar la web cada 60 segundos.

Comment: @MarceloForclaz sin duda alguna es mucho mejor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para eso deberás utilizar algún método como el paso de datos a través de Ajax de forma que sin recargar la página, la tabla se actualice con los datos más recientes cada X tiempo.

Echa un ojo a este enlace:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Preguntas basadas en opiniones no se deben responder

Comment: Él ha hecho una pregunta y yo le he dado una respuesta no?? Algunos os pasais de puristas.

Comment: Por lo visto no entiendes muy bien como funciona este sitio web @PabloGonzález, además tu referencia es un sitio que tiene mala reputación en el mundo de la programación.

Comment: No es ser purista, así son las reglas; además esto más que una respuesta concreta es solo una opinión

Comment: Un poco lamentable que vayas buscando mis preguntas para darle votos negativos. Allá cada uno. Buenas tardes.

Comment: a que te refieres @PabloGonzález ?